# Check if a child key exists using JSON.Net (vb)

Tags: json, vb.net, json.net

I have a JObject that contains the following JToken:

```
{
   "widgets":{
      "collect_survey":{
         "ToCountry":"US"
      },
      "details":{
         "ToCountry":"US"
      },
      "check_survey":{
         
      }
   }
}
```

I'm trying to check for the true/false if a child object exists. Can't figure out what the syntax is.

Works:

```
Dim _res As JObject = Execution.Context
Dim _res1 = _res.ContainsKey("widgets")
```

Does not work:

```
Dim _res1 = _res.ContainsKey("widgets.collect_survey")
Dim _res1 = _res("widgets").ContainsKey("widgets")
```

Comment: Have you considered a method that uses recursion?

Comment: `Dim _res1 = DirectCast(_res("widgets"), JObject).ContainsKey("collect_survey")` -- `_res("widgets")` returns a JToken, not a JObject

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`SelectToken()`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SelectToken.htm) to select a nested child, then check if the returned value is not `Nothing`.  This method supports [JSONPath syntax](https://goessner.net/articles/JsonPath/) for selecting values at any level in the JSON hierarchy:

```
Dim hasSurvey = _res.SelectToken("widgets.collect_survey") IsNot Nothing
```

Alternatively, you could chain together [child lookups](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JToken_Item.htm) using the [null conditional operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/operators/null-conditional-operators):

```
Dim hasSurvey = _res("widgets")?("collect_survey") IsNot Nothing
```

Notes:

- [`JObject.ContainsKey(string)`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JObject_ContainsKey.htm) only checks to see if the current JSON object has a property with the specified name.  Thus `_res.ContainsKey("widgets.collect_survey")` would return true for a JSON with a property of that name, such as:

  ```json
  {
    "widgets.collect_survey" : { /* some values */ }
  }
  ```
- The [`JObject` indexer](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JObject_Item_1.htm) returns null when the specified key is not present rather than throwing a `KeyNotFoundException`, so there is no need to call `ContainsKey()` before getting the value.

Demo fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/2bldNL).