# Why doesn't JObject.ContainsKey find a key that JToken.SelectToken can get value from using the same key?

Tags: c#, linq, json.net

I'm very new to JSON, but I need to get the length values from a JSON file as follows. An object has either the key "length" followed by a numeric value, or those numeric values assigned to certain "nodes", A1, B1 etc.

```json
[{
    "id": "S211",
    "length": 100
},
{
    "id": "S212",
    "length": {
        "B1": 210,
        "B2": 240
    }
},
{
    "id": "S213",
    "length": {
        "A1": 65,
        "A2": 100
    }
}]
```

However, as all "node" values don't always exist, I thought some sort of null check was in order. If a key is missing then the value for the corresponding variable should be set to -1. In this example the value of `lengthB1` should be assigned:

```CS
public TrackCircuit(JObject TC) 
{
    short lengthB1;

    // Always fails and returns -1. Should return value if the key is found
    lengthB1 = TC.ContainsKey("length.B1") ? (short)TC.SelectToken("length.B1") : (short)-1; 

    // Assigns correct value if there is one. Generates an exception if length.B1 isn't found
    lengthB1 = (short)TC.SelectToken("length.B1");
}
```

I do not understand why the key `length.B1` doesn't exist for the `ContainsKey` method, but the very same key returns a value when used in a `SelectToken` method.

Comment: And if  you learn, you will find out that JObject ContainsKey determines whether the JSON object has the specified property name.  Do your json string contains  "length.B1" property ?

Comment: you must use Pattern SelectTokens to get values example "TC.SelectTokens("..*.[?(@.length.B1)]") "

Comment: [`JObject.ContainsKey()`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JObject_ContainsKey.htm) looks to see whether a property with a specific name exists **in the object itself**, so  `TC.ContainsKey("length.B1")` looks for a property `"length.B1" : 210`.  See e.g. [Check if a child key exists using JSON.Net (vb)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76502491/3744182).

Comment: You don't need `ContainsKey()` anyway, just check whether `TC.SelectToken()` returns `null` e.g. as follows: `lengthB1 = (short?)TC.SelectToken("length.B1").ValueOrDefault(-1);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cause of the error is that you are using an incorrect key to check for a property in the JSON object. The key “length.B1” represents a JSON path, not a property name. A JSON path is a string that locates an element in a JSON structure using separators such as a dot or brackets. The ContainsKey method does not support JSON paths, it only accepts a property name.

Comment: It took a while to get back to this, but I think I get it now. Found the following solution to my problem and suddenly your answer is clear as day, thanks. `lengthB1 = TC.SelectToken("length").Value<short?>("B1") ?? -1;`

Answer (score 0):

JObject ContainsKey determines whether the JSON object has the specified property name. You can use json path  with SelectToken

```
    var lengthB1 = (short?)TC.SelectToken("length.B1");
    if (lengthB1 == null) lengthB1 = -1;
```

And BTW you have an exception because null can not be cast to short. You have to use nullable short? type

but I would prefer to add some validation

```
short lengthB1;
var length = TC.SelectToken("length.B2");
if  (length == null || length.Type != JTokenType.Integer) lengthB1 = -1;
        else lengthB1=(short)length;
```

to make it working with TC.SelectToken("length") too

Answer (score 0):

you can use ToObject to convert and check values.
in example i am selecting B1 value - as requested

```
void Main()
{
    string json = "[{\"id\":\"S211\",\"length\":100},{\"id\":\"S212\",\"length\":{\"B1\":210,\"B2\":240}},{\"id\":\"S213\",\"length\":{\"A1\":65,\"A2\":100}}]";
    var jobj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JToken>(json);
    TrackCircuit(jobj);
}

public void TrackCircuit(JToken TC)
{
    TC.Children().Select(s => new
    {
        id = s["id"].ToString(),
        //to show if it string or an object
        isB1 = (s["length"].ToArray().Count() > 0),

        length = (s["length"].ToArray().Count() > 0)
                    ? (int?)s["length"].ToObject<len>().B2
                    : (int?)s["length"],

        anotherApproach = (s["length"].Value<JToken>().HasValues)
                    ? s["length"].Value<JToken>().Children<JProperty>().Where(w=> w.Name == "B1").Select(s=> s.Value).FirstOrDefault()
                    : s["length"].ToString()
            
        
}).Dump();
}

public class len
{
    public int? A1 { get; set; }
    public int? A2 { get; set; }
    public int? B1 { get; set; }
    public int? B2 { get; set; }
}
```

result:

[image]

Comment: also you can use If(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(result.Value<JObject>()["FIELDNAME"].Value<String>()))
{
 //Your Logic 

}